# How can I draw an outline around my raster classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

I have a raster created from polygon shapes from a social survey of fishing areas in ArcMap. I have classified my raster to 3 classes High,Low,Medium. I want to draw a border or an outline around the raster classes so it is visible like a hollowed effect in three colours so areas that are High, Low, Medium are visible. How can I do this?

Comment: This may end up being cartographically difficult to read. Since your classes share boundaries, as polylines you'll probably only see one color without some tweaking of geometry or symbology. That, combined with how complex your map is, might make it difficult to tell which side of the boundary line is the enclosed area for the matching color/class.

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps I would take.

1. If you don't have an attribute table for you raster already I would use the tool, [Build Raster Attribute Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m2000000).
2. Open the attribute table for your raster and click to select the class you want to export. You could also probably do this by using the tool, [Select By Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000).
3. Then I would use the [Raster to Polygon Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000008000000) to create a shapefile of the selected field.
4. Then for the shapefile created I would set the fill to hollow and the outline to a the desired color.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 for the other two classes.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you cannot do that with a raster, you need to convert your raster back into a polygon Feature Class if you want a hollow effect. This [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000008000000) will do it.